# x = something(x) as something(x)

Tags: c#, lambda, mono, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D, which supports mono 2.6ish, for a gui element, I'd write this

```
SomeProperty = GUI.FloatField(SomeProperty);
```

However I would like to write something like

```
GUI.FloatFieldFor(SomeProperty);
```

How would I go about doing this? Note that SomeProperty is a float, and this GUI stuff goes in an OnGUI method which is called every frame, so I don't have to roll my own PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not experienced in Mono or Unity3D, but you should be able to pass it by reference.

```
// Method
public void FloatFieldFor(ref float value)
{
   value *= value; // or whatever
}

// Call method
GUI.FloatFieldFor(ref SomeProperty);
```

Comment: Let me know if I misunderstood your question.